# Ubuntu 13.10 touchpad problem

Tags: 13.10, touchpad

Hey guys i have problem with my laptop in Ubuntu, I don't know how exactly to describe it.
Every time I the cursor with Touch Pad and stops its will automatically do a right mouse click, also when i click the right mouse button it will take a second to start dragging ?!!? Sorry for the bad description if there any outputs please tell me what to do because i don't know how to deal with such things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar issues with my Logitech touchpad in 13.10, but after updating the to latest 14.04 build it has been fixed.  I used to not be able to right click and select an option - the first one would always be selected as soon as I started to move to the option I wanted.  Now in 14.04 I can right click and touch scroll to the option I want.  There must have been something fixed in 14.04 to support touchpad use?